# Progress bar in UIWebView

Tags: ios, cocoa, uiwebview, progress-bar, nsurlconnection

How to determine progress in `UIWebView?`
Few Observations:
1. To determine the progress of downloaded content, we need to make a `NSURLConnection` object and fetch data twice: one with the `UIWebView` and the other with `NSURLConnection`
2. If we just fetch data once using `NSURLConnection` and load the webview with that data text/html then that data renders poorly

Difficulties:
a) As fetching data twice can largely slow down the process, is it feasible (appstore safe?) to use private api's like the one given here: https://github.com/petr-inmite/imtwebview

b) If we cannot, then how we may display a progress bar?

c) Also will downloading the data asynchronously using `NSURLConnection` mirror the progress of `UIWebView` loading? How bad the performance of fetching data twice would be?

There are some browsers like safari, dolphin which are displaying progress bar...any ideas on how to do this???

Comment: [This](https://github.com/dzenbot/DZWebBrowser) might of some interest for you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Progress Bar in Cocoa](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9701273/progress-bar-in-cocoa)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `UIWebView` delegates for it.First set your webview's delegate to be `self` and then utilize these methods.Prior to this create and add a spinner to the view which shall indicate the progress of uiwebview e.g `UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner`

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)localWebView {

    [ spinner performSelectorInBackground: @selector(startAnimating) withObject: nil];
}

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {

    [ spinner performSelectorInBackground: @selector(stopAnimating) withObject: nil];

}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)localWebView {

    [ spinner performSelectorInBackground: @selector(stopAnimating) withObject: nil];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But instead of the spinningwheel, it would be better to display the progress bar...There are plenty of browsers doing it: Safari, dolphin, luna, mercury etc...